# Configure WinRM using a .bat file without yes/no prompt

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, winrm

I want to configure winrm in all my clients using a bat file.
after running bat file `winrm quickconfig` command there's a prompt for a yes/no answer. I don't know how to answer "yes" in the batch file.

Comment: Can you post the script you have written ?

Comment: this is the code : winrm quickconfig and i tried to force a yes answer by using "echo y" and that didin't work.

Comment: In general, if you want to run an interactive command-line tool non-interactively, you need to find a command line switch. Often, it's something like `/y`, `-y`, `/q`, `-q` (for "yes" or "quiet"). Generally, more details can be found by running `command /?` (Windows/DOS), `cmnd --help` or `man cmnd` (Unix/Linux), or `Get-Help Ridiculously-Long-Command-Name` (PowerShell).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding the parameter `-quiet` to the quickconfig call will suppress the yes/no prompt, and do what you want.

```
winrm quickconfig -quiet
```

Comment: well! that worked! Many TNX